# ag-grid: How to select the all the rows on click of header checkbox for multiple pages with server side pagination in the ag-grid table

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I would like to select the `ids` of all the rows on click of header `checkbox` for ag-grid `table` with server-side `pagination` enabled. Currently I am able to retain only the active page table rows ids but I want to select ids of multiple pages with ag-grid server-side pagination.

I tried with `getSelectedNodes()` and `getSelectedRows()` apis of `rowSelected` events of ag-grid but it gives me only the current page data not the multiple page data.

Please let me know how can I get the data from multiple pages rows selection with server side pagination.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the server-side row model, then only the rows in the current page exist on the client side. That's the whole point of the server-side row model.

So, in your case, the grid doesn't have any data about the rows that are not in the current page.

The only way to know the ids of all of the rows is to ask the server (presumably via an api call).

In this mode, I'm not sure what you expect as far as "selecting" rows that aren't actually in the grid, but if you want your UI to act like you are using the client-side row model with respect to selection, you are going to have to manage that yourself, by having your component maintain a list of all row ids, and  which are 'selected', and then using the grid's api to select rows in the current page that you have in your 'selected row' list whenever a new page gets loaded.